# Send email in asp.net mvc without using credentials like in php

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to send an email in `ASP.NET MVC` without using credentials like in `PHP`.

In `PHP` I simply use the `mail` method to send an email without using any credentials. How can I do the same thing in `C#`?

Comment: Yes it is possible. All the credentials can be saved in Web.Config. please google "How to send email using ASP.NET MVC"

Comment: I did, but what I get is that I have to use the credentials, that is why I asked my question on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It'll use default credentials.

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

mail.From = new MailAddress(EMAIL_FROM_WHICH_YOU_WANT_TO_SEND_EMAIL);
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(EMAIL_TO_WHOM_YOU_WANT_TO_SEND_EMAIL));
mail.Subject = YOUR_SUBJECT;

mail.Body = BODY_OF_EMAIL;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true/false[BASED_ON_YOUR_BODY];

smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

and you'll need to add this in `web.config` file.

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
    <smtp from="[URL]" deliveryMethod="network">
    <network host="localhost" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" />
    </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Feel free to mark as answer, if it helped you.

Comment: "network"  =>  "Network"   // the deliveryMethod is invalid